# Authentication and redirection problem in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have created a logic where I have a custom registraion form which includes user registration details and city adding details

My logic is registering the user but it is not logging in and redirecting the page to /admin/home and it is not even sending the email verification 
I have to be logged in my self and send mail again to do that

I want that when someone submits this form first user should be created and logged in and redirect to /admin/home and after verifying the verification the city should be saved in that database

```
class QuickRegisterController extends Controller
{

    public function quickList(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::firstOrCreate([
            'name' => $request->owner_of_the_room,
            'email' => $request->owner_working_email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
            'role_id' => config('quickadmin.default_role_id'),
        ]);

        if (\Auth::check() && \Auth::user()->email_verified_at){
            $city = new TotalCity;
            $city->name = $request->location_id;
            $city->created_by_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        }
        return redirect('/admin/home');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
public function quickList(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::firstOrCreate([
        'name' => $request->owner_of_the_room,
        'email' => $request->owner_working_email,
        'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        'role_id' => config('quickadmin.default_role_id'),
    ]);
    \Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
    if (\Auth::check()){
        $city = new TotalCity;
        $city->name = $request->location_id;
        $city->created_by_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $city->save();
        return redirect()->to('/admin/home');
    }else{
       return redirect()->back();
    }


}
```

Comment: Yess thank fully it has redirected to /admin/home but verification email is not been sending still

Comment: and the city data is also not saving in database

Comment: i was forgot to write  $city->save();

Comment: and in your code there is no code for sending verification mail.